# How to update data from one table to another using jpa efficiently

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I have a linux centos system, and am using postgres PostgreSQL 9.4.11 database.

I have a messaging system in which messages gets stored in db and there receipts are inserted in to the same table with the updated status (so for 1 message 3 rows are added in the table), everyday million rows are inserted into it due to which generating reports from that table takes a lot time. I don't have control over that table to make it store the updated status in the same row.

I tried data table partitioning to improve it but it was not that much useful.

So to overcome this, I started storing the sent messages in two tables and when I receive the receipt I update the second table same row and generate reports from that. To do this I tried using trigger but trigger were enormously slow and to update 100k rows it took 12 hours approx.

Third option that I tried is that I created a scheduler in java which queries 100 records from the large table and updates the records in the new table by its correct id. 
Doing this one by one is not efficient at all as it increases the server load as well as takes time to update data.

I tried the following batch update method to update all receipts in one go:
I added all id's in array and set the required status and time and did execute update, but this didn't work, the arrids array shows 1000 records and the update count shows only 20 or 50 records  updated (shows some random count).

```
queryStm = "Update reciept set smsc_sub=:dlr,time_sub=:time,serverTime=:servertime  where id IN :arrids ";


Query query  = em.createNativeQuery(queryStm);
            query.setParameter("arrids ",arrids );
            query.setParameter("dlr", dlr);
            query.setParameter("time", time);
            query.setParameter("servertime", new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));

            query.executeUpdate();
```

Is there any efficient way to achieve updating data into one table from another table either in java/jpa or in postgres.

Comment: A random number from the update statement sounds odd.  How many rows do you get back if you change your statement to a select?

Comment: Obfuscation layers like JPA  and "efficiently" and don't go together - especially not for bulk operations

Comment: It shows 1000 rows fetched and updates only 50 to 60 rows ,I even added maxoffset to 100 but then it updated 20 to 30 rows @Chris

Comment: This is a native SQL query, so its not an issue with JPA and you'll have to debug the SQL being used in the database.  Are you sure that "select count(distinct id) from reciept where id in :arrids" is returning 1000, or were you looking at the number of arrids being used in the query.